# TypeScript subtype checking

Tags: typescript

If I have an interface:

```
export interface IChartDatum {
    values: {
        x: number|Date,
        y: number
    }[],
    key: string;
    disabled: boolean;
    area?: boolean;
}
```

why while interacting with a collection of: `private chartData:IChartDatum[] = [];`

The following is correctly invalid:

```
this.chartData.push({
  values: [{x: "2", y: "5"}],
  key: status.name,
  disabled: status.name == 'archived'
});
```

But this is wrongly valid:

```
this.chartData.find(item => item.key == status.name)
.values.push({x:"2", y: "5"});
```

[image]

Comment: Your first example has a typo error in it. In any case, with the typo corrected both examples generate the same type error when I try them.

Comment: maybe its webstorm only?

Comment: might be, I've seen a lot of people complain about typescript support in webstorm. In visual studio code it works just fine.

Comment: It would help if the code you posted is a drop-in, minimal repro of your problem. I'd also suggest creating *seperate* cases for both scenarios to make sure one doesn't affect the other (e.g. the compiler might get confused at the first error and miss a second one...).

Comment: No, still doesn't show any errors when I correct the first one. Your answer seems to be on the money dude, so if you add it as an answer, you can cash in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Webstorm's lacking TypeScript support.

Both given cases generate the same type matching error in Visual Studio Code.